# Calling a command line utility from Python

Tags: python, terminal, debian, strace

I am currently trying to utilize strace to automatically trace a programm 's system calls. To then parse and process the data obtained, I want to use a Python script.

I now wonder, how would I go about calling strace from Python?
Strace is usually called via command line and I don't know of any C library compiled from strace which I could utilize.

What is the general way to simulate an access via command line via Python?
alternatively: are there any tools similar to strace written natively in Python?

I'm thankful for any kind of help.

Nothing, as I'm clueless

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `subprocess` module.

It has `check_output` to read the output and put it in a variable, and `check_call` to just check the exit code.

If you want to run a shell script you can write it all in a string and set `shell=True`, otherwise just put the parameters as strings in a list.

```
import subprocess
# Single process
subprocess.check_output(['fortune', '-m', 'ciao'])
# Run it in a shell
subprocess.check_output('fortune | grep a', shell=True)
```

Remember that if you run stuff in a shell, if you don't escape properly and allow user data to go in your string, it's easy to make security holes. It is better to not use `shell=True`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use commands as the following:

```
import commands
cmd = "strace command"
result = commands.getstatusoutput(cmd)
if result[0] == 0:
   print result[1]
else:
   print "Something went wrong executing your command"
```

`result[0]` contains the return code, and `result[1]` contains the output.

Comment: You know python has a `subprocess` module and there is absolutely no need to depend on other libraries?

Comment: `subprocess.check_output('fortune | grep a', shell=True)` there, no more dependency to your useless module.

Answer (score 0):

**Python 2 and Python 3 (prior 3.5)**

Simply execute:

```
subprocess.call(["strace", "command"])
```

Execute and return the output for processing:

```
output = subprocess.check_output(["strace", "command"])
```

Reference: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

**Python 3.5+**

```
output = subprocess.run(["strace", "command"], caputure_output=True)
```

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run